# refresh / reset jquery variable after ajax form send

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble figuring this one out, can anyone help please?

I'm not sure if it's even possible, I need to refresh/reset the variable as I need to keep it's scope for other functions, so it can be used globally.

I have this variable near the top of my jquery goodness...

```
var heightOne = $panelOne.height();
```

and I'm trying to refresh it when my ajax gravity form sends.

I have this binded function which will fire when the form has fulled reloaded, So I guess I can put my variable refresh/reset script inside here...

```
$(document).bind('gform_post_render', function(){

    // variable refresh code in here...     

    $slidePane.css({ 'height' : heightOne + 'px' }); // then this will follow and use new height taken from $panelOne updated variable  

});
```

But I'm struggling to find out where to start. Any help would be awesome thanks.

---

**UPDATE**

This is my script in full, to show you what I'm trying achieve.

```
$(window).load(function(){

    var $slidePane  = $("#sliding-pane"),

         $stageOne  = $("#nav-stage-1"),
         $stageTwo  = $("#nav-stage-2"),
         $stageThree = $("#nav-stage-3"),

         heightOne  = $("#panel-stage-1").height(),
         heightTwo  = $("#panel-stage-2").height(),
         heightThree = $("#panel-stage-3").height();

    $slidePane.css({ 'height' : heightOne + 'px' });

    $.fn.slideThree = function() {

        $slidePane.stop().animate({
                left : "0px",
                height : heightOne + 'px'
        }, 300);

        FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0, 510);

    };

    $.fn.slideThree = function() {

        $slidePane.stop().animate({
                left : "-680px",
                height : heightTwo + 'px'
        }, 300);

        FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0, 510);

    };

    $.fn.slideThree = function() {

        $slidePane.stop().animate({
                left : "-1360px",
                height : heightThree + 'px'
        }, 300);

        FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0, 510);

    };

    $stageOne.on('click', function () {

        $(this).slideOne();

    });

    $stageTwo.on('click', function () {

        $(this).slideTwo();

    });

    $stageThree.on('click', function () {

        $(this).slideThree();

    });

    $(document).bind('gform_post_render', function(){

        $slidePane.css({ 'height' : heightThree + 'px' });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you put `overflow:hidden` in the css of the slidePane; that way the dimensions will resize automatically. You shouldn't need jquery for this.

Comment: That would be an ideal solution, however this div is running as a slide on a carousel - and needs a defined height. Thanks

Comment: If you really want jquery, then $slidePane.css('height', heightOne); should work provided that on the call back you set the variable with the height you need. Also, make sure $slidePane is in scope. It's hard to see what's going on because you're not showing much.

Comment: I think you need to understand how overflow works; you shouldn't have to specify heights if your HTML/CSS is good.

Comment: I am 100% overflow can save me today - it's a carousel slider and all my slides are different sizes. Meaning if my containing div `$slidePane` uses overflow instead, it will always be the height of the highest div - plus I am animating the height from slide to slide. I just need the variable `$panelOne` to update when my form refreshes. Thanks

Comment: I am 100% overflow can't save me today* - typo

Comment: Hello, I've added my full script so you can see what is going on. When the binded gform_post_render function fires, the variable 'heightThree' value is still the same original as the original document load. I need this variable to update the value somehow.

Comment: It's because there's no call back! You want to have the trigger kick in AFTER the data is received. At the moment, it seems like it's firing at the same time the requests is leaving. You want to use $.ajax and use the success function to trigger the repaint.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $slidePane  = $("#sliding-pane"),
    /* ...other vars... */
    heightThree = $("#panel-stage-3").height();

    // Cache the height
    $('#panel-stage-3').data('origHeight', heightThree);


$(document).bind('gform_post_render', function(){
    $slidePane.css({ 'height' : $('#panel-stage-3').data('origHeight') + 'px' });
});
```

Comment: Hmmm is there anyway to use this with my bind functions I am using it on a wordpress gravity form? Thanks

Comment: Hello, I've added my full script so you can see what is going on. When the binded gform_post_render function fires, the variable 'heightThree' value is still the same original as the original document load. I need this variable to update the value somehow.

Comment: Based on your newly provided code, I'd recommend a simple data cache and reference. See my edit.